# Codeigniter route "mysite.com/$username" to "users/profile/username"

Tags: regex, codeigniter, routes

I want to load a profile of user from "users/profile/username" where username is same as $username (without $ sign), How can I define rule for this routing?

I do want to keep "$" in my url for some reason.

it means when mysite.com/$username is typed, CI will route this request to mysite.com/users/profile/username (no $ sign now, as it is just to identify that the request is for 'username' and its not a controller)

Answer (score 0):

add $ in config:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-+$';
```

however, this may be security hole

in route use:

```
$route['mysite.com/(:any)'] = 'users/profile/$1'
```

Comment: with this method you will need to make sure that any other routes that you have are listed in the routes.php file before `$route['mysite.com/(:any)'] = 'users/profile/$1'` else all requests will be routed there.

Comment: This $route['mysite.com/(:any)'] = 'users/profile/$1' will serve the purpose BUT... if I use it... I will force all my controllers to pass through this "users/profile", I don't want to do that. One of the reason, I have $ sign before usernames is because it will tell the system that this is a username, so load this profile. without $ codeigniter will take it as a call for controller or method. I hope you get my point. I don't want someone to have a username of lets say 'users' as this is my class name? If a string starts with a $ sign with and then text/num, rest is username...

Comment: so if someone has username of let say 'users' it will not be a problem for codeigniter because whenever this profile is loaded, it will be like this mysite.com/$users, in this case CI knows where to send this request ofcourse users/profile/users